# How do I create multiple router outlet dynamically inside *ngFor in angular 2.4.2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular2 (2.4.2) and I am trying to create multiple router outlets dynamically like this:

Sample code-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router  }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

   <div *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{number}}</div>

   <div *ngFor="let number of numbers">
     <router-outlet name="{{number}}"></router-outlet>
   </div>

   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
numbers:any;

constructor(){
  this.numbers = [0,1,2,3,4];
}

}
```

But I was getting this error for router-outlet inside the `*ngFor` :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

    <div *ngFor="let number of numbers">
      [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

"): AppComponent@5:6
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </div>

   [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  "): AppComponent@8:3 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

To avoid the error above I added router module in the imports section and RouterOutletMap in the providers section of AppModule.

After that, I started getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'.
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("

    <div *ngFor="let number of numbers">
      <router-outlet [ERROR ->]name="{{number}}"></router-outlet>
    </div>

"): AppComponent@5:21 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

Can some one point out my mistake? How do I create multiple router outlets dynamically based on requirement?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why do you want to create multiple **<router-outlet>**? is there any particular reason?

Comment: Because I want to load same component in multiple times and each will have their state and data maintained through out the session. You can imagine like browser where you can load google in multiple tabs.

Comment: update your **app.module.ts** and relevant codes to your post.

Comment: `name` is not an input of `router-outlet`. It just reads the attribute. This means it cannot be a variable. If you want to load the same component multiple times, why do you need the `router-outlet`? Just load the component multiple times.

Comment: Components are loaded from menu navigations. This will depends on user how many times user wants to open same component in different area.

Comment: Hello. Did you ever figure out how to fix this? I'm in the same boat :(

Comment: Hello. Did you ever figure out how to fix this?